# what is a RoR best practice? match by id or different column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I had a terrible morning.  Lots of emails floating around about why things don't work.  Upon investigating I found that there is a data mismatch which is causing errors.

**Scenario**
`Customer` and `Address` are two tables.

`Customer` contains

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :address, :foreign_key => "id"        
end
```

`Address` Contains

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer, :foreign_key => "cid"    
end
```

So the two tables match on `id` which is the default and that column is auto incremented.

**Problem**
on the edit Page we have some code like this.

```
params[:line1] = @customer.first.address.line1
```

It fails because no matching record is found for a customer in the address table.  I don't know why this is happening. It seems that over time a lot of records did not get added to `Address` table.  Now problem is that when a new `Customer` is added (say with id 500) the `Address` will be added with some other id (say 425) ...now you don't know which address belongs to which customer.

**Question**
Being new to Rails, I am asking whether it is always considered good to create an extra column for joining of the records, rather than depending on the column that is automatically incremented?  If I had a seperate column in `Address` table where I would manually insert the recently added customers id then this issue would not have come up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `has_one`-`belongs_to` relationship should result in the "belonging" model having the key of the "having" model. Or, in other words, the `:foreign_key` clause should be the same in both models.

If I have these:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, :foreign_key => 'cid' # note foreign_key same as in Address
end
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, :foreign_key => 'cid' # note foreign_key same as in Customer
end
```

then I can do this:

```
>> cust = Customer.create(:name=>'Mr Custard')
+----+------------+
| id | name       |
+----+------------+
| 1  | Mr Custard |
+----+------------+
1 row in set
>> add = cust.create_address(:line_1 => '42 Some Street', :line_2 => 'Some where')
+----+-----+----------------+------------+
| id | cid | line_1         | line_2     |
+----+-----+----------------+------------+
| 1  | 1   | 42 Some Street | Some where |
+----+-----+----------------+------------+
1 row in set
```

checking:

```
>> Customer.first.address
+----+-----+----------------+------------+
| id | cid | line_1         | line_2     |
+----+-----+----------------+------------+
| 1  | 1   | 42 Some Street | Some where |
+----+-----+----------------+------------+
1 row in set
>> Address.first.customer
+----+------------+
| id | name       |
+----+------------+
| 1  | Mr Custard |
+----+------------+
```

and my database looks like this:

```
sqlite> select * from customers;
1|Mr Custard
sqlite> select * from addresses;
1|1|42 Some Street|Some where
```

(the nice table output for ActiveRecord results comes from [Hirb](http://github.com/cldwalker/hirb), by the way)

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation.  Curious, say that you now go in and run the following query `update Address set id = 100 where id = 1` (doing this because I deploy on heroku and am fed up with having to reset autoincrement) so after that update query...will your association still work?

Comment: The association should work regardless of the value of `id`.  But there's rarely a good reason to modify a record's primary key like that.  What don't you like about the default behavior of autoincrement?

Comment: @Tom - the OP didn't specify, but the most likely reason for not using the convention is that there's a legacy schema involved. Otherwise, I can't think of a good reason not to follow convention.

Comment: @Omnipresent - Updating Address.id shouldn't cause a problem, because ActiveRecord doesn't think Customer needs to know it - Address holds the foreign key link, which is enough to allow navigation in either direction in a one-to-one relationship. If you update Customer.cid, then you'd need to ensure Address was kept in synch.

Answer (score 1):

The Rails' convention is for each table to have an auto-incrementing integer primary key column named `id` and additionally—in your example—for the `addresses` table to have a non auto-incrementing integer foreign key column named `customer_id`. As the name implies, this holds the primary key value from the associated record in the `customers` table.

If you follow these rules then there's no need to specify a `:foreign_key` option on the associations.

Comment: You'd do `@address = @customer.build_address(:line_1 => '...', :line_2 => '...')`